# how to scan a database row into a pointer to a structure?

Tags: pointers, go

from what i understand when i write a method on a pointer receiver i can modify the values, lets say i have this structure

```
type User Struct {
  ID uint64
  Name string
  Avatar *string
  // other fields
}

func (user *User) Update() error {

  sql := `UPDATE users SET "avatar" = $1 RETURNING *`

  err := models.DB.QueryRow(sql, user.Avatar).Scan(
    user.ID,       // &user.ID works
    user.Name,    // &user.Name works
    user.Avatar, // &user.Avatar works
  )

  return err   

}
```

so technically if `user` is a pointer to a structure this code should work? but when i call the `Update` method i get `receiver is not a pointer` error, what am i missing?

Comment: You wrote the answer in the code, are you just asking why?

Comment: @JimB yes i don't understand why that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Though `user` is a pointer in your method, you're not passing `user` to `Scan`, you're passing the field values. When you write

```
user.ID
```

It's equivalent to

```
(*user).ID // this copies the ID value
```

(see the relevant section of [Selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors) in the spec)

In order to get the address of the ID field, you need to use the `&` operator

```
&user.ID // takes the address of ID
```